# Python - converting text from HTML file into a csv without unique identifier tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've used beautifulsoup4 to scrape some information I want from a web page which lists the details for a psychiatrist practice and managed to get this part back with the key info.

```
<h5>Practice Locations</h5>
    <p>Springfield, 1234<br/> 08 1234 5678</p>
    <p>Shelbyville, 1234<br/>08 1234 5678</p>
<h5>Gender:</h5>
    <p>Male<br/></p>
<h5>Languages spoken (other than English):</h5>
    <p>Spanish<br/></p>
    <p>Italian<br/></p>
<h5>Problem areas treated:</h5>
    <p>Anxiety disorders<br/>Mood disorders<br/>Sexual disorders<br/></p>
<h5>Populations treated:</h5>
<p>Adult<br/>Young adult<br/></p>
<h5>Subspecialty areas:</h5>
    <p>Cancer patients<br/>Gender issues<br/>Pain management<br/>Specialist psychotherapist<br/></p>
<h5>Treatments and services offered:</h5>
    <p>Does not prescribe psychotropics<br/>Psychotherapy – cognitive behavioural therapy (CBT)<br/>Psychotherapy – hypnotherapy<br/>Psychotherapy – interpersonal<br/>Psychotherapy – marital therapy<br/></p>
<h5>Practice details:</h5>
    <p>Can bulk bill selected patients<br/></p>
<p> </p>
```

I want to put the information under each heading into a column of a .csv file but I can't figure out how to do this because the headings don't have unique identifiers in any way. I know I have to use the headings to demarcate the separate columns in some way, but I'm totally new to python and not sure how to go about it.

It would be easy to do manually but I'd like to collect this information from a lot of pages formatted this same way.
To make things more complicated, some pages are missing the info for some of these heading (eg. they don't list the populations treated or subspeciality) so I have to take check that each heading is there before trying to collect that info.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You use the `h5` tags as headers:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import itertools
headers = [i.text for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all('h5')]
full_data = [[i.text, i] for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all(re.compile('h5|p'))]
new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(full_data, key=lambda x:x[0] in headers)]
grouped = [new_data[i]+new_data[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)]
final_data = {c:{i:str(h)[3:-4].split('<br/>')[1:] for i, h in results} for [_, [[c, _]], _, results] in grouped}
```

Output:

```
{'Practice Locations': {'Springfield, 1234 08 1234 5678': [' 08 1234 5678'], 'Shelbyville, 123408 1234 5678': ['08 1234 5678']}, 'Gender:': {'Male': ['']}, 'Languages spoken (other than English):': {'Spanish': [''], 'Italian': ['']}, 'Problem areas treated:': {'Anxiety disordersMood disordersSexual disorders': ['Mood disorders', 'Sexual disorders', '']}, 'Populations treated:': {'AdultYoung adult': ['Young adult', '']}, 'Subspecialty areas:': {'Cancer patientsGender issuesPain managementSpecialist psychotherapist': ['Gender issues', 'Pain management', 'Specialist psychotherapist', '']}, 'Treatments and services offered:': {'Does not prescribe psychotropicsPsychotherapy – cognitive behavioural therapy (CBT)Psychotherapy – hypnotherapyPsychotherapy – interpersonalPsychotherapy – marital therapy': ['Psychotherapy – cognitive behavioural therapy (CBT)', 'Psychotherapy – hypnotherapy', 'Psychotherapy – interpersonal', 'Psychotherapy – marital therapy', '']}, 'Practice details:': {'Can bulk bill selected patients': [''], ' ': []}}
```